# Symfony2 Basic Auth Athentication except localhost

Tags: symfony

I want to configure my security.yml in my project to require Basic Auth from all hosts excluding localhost? Is it possible? I've tried to found solution on the Web, but ineffective.

Comment: did you try the regexp negation in the security pattern?

Comment: Can you can give me any example of that solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a request matcher.

You can follow this great tutorial to enable the request matcher http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-using-advanced-request-matchers-to-activate-firewalls/

Only follow the "Creating an advanced request matcher" and "Hook the request matcher in the security configuration" sections though.

Your match method would look like this:

```
return 'localhost' == $request->getHost();
```